# self-inductance, back-emf

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

In self-inductance calculations, why the back emf is in negative sign? 
For example: it is given that the emf induced in the solemoid is 5.0V in the question.
E=-L(dI/dt)
-5.0=-L(dI/dt)…
Something like this. Why there is a negative sign in front of 5.0V ?
Thank you.

Comment: The negative sign is there in Maxwell's equation:  $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$ and the inductor equation must be consistent with this.  Or are you asking why the negative sign in this equation?

Comment: I know E= - L(dI/dt), and the negative sign in the equation means that the induced emf opposes the increase in the magnetic flux. The thing that confuses me is when we substitute E=5.0 in the equation, why we need to put a negative sign again, make the equation becomes: -5.0= - L (dI/dt). [ 2 negative signs]. Why not 5.0= -L (dI/dt). This appeared when i doing some questions about self-inductance. Is it related with something else? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some confusion due to failing to distinguish between the emf $\mathcal{E}$ and the potential difference $v_L$ across the inductor.

For example, if a battery of voltage $V$ is connected across an inductor, you will measure a voltage $V$ across the inductor and, in the case of an ideal inductor, you will find that the rate of change of inductor current $i_L$ is (assuming the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention))

$$\frac{di_L}{dt} = \frac{V}{L}$$

since, for an ideal inductor, we have

$$v_L = L \frac{di_L}{dt}$$

The associated emf $\mathcal{E}$ is of the opposite sign since it must 'oppose' the applied voltage if the inductor current is to be finite and so, in the above case, we have

$$\mathcal{E} = - V = - L \frac{di_L}{dt}$$.

Answer (score 0):

The self inductance is a characteristic property by which a current carrying coil generates some emf across it against the applied emf that makes a current flow through the coil. The principle is as follows.
When a current starts to flow through a coil, the magnetic flux linked with the coil changes and this happens only for a few seconds. This change in magnetic flux induces a curling electric field as given by Faraday's law. This electric field induces an emf on the coil in a direction opposite to the cause that causes a changing magnetic flux. The changing magnetic flux is the increase in current. So the induced emf opposes this applied emf to produce a current in the circuit. The energy required for this is stored in the magnetic field of the coil. So the induced emf has a polarity opposite to the applied field. This is why the back emf is represented by a negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as blowing up a balloon. When you release the balloon the flow is in the opposite direction to when it was inflated.The pressure (voltage) opposes the inflation.

Comment: I've always thought a balloon was pretty good analogy for a capacitor (with one plate grounded).  The pressure is analogous to voltage and the flow of air is analogous to current.  For an inductor, however, I've considered a ducted fan with some moment of inertia.  Changes in the flow of air (or other fluid) through the duct are opposed by the fan by creating a pressure that opposes the change.